# wpf xaml how to binding element name datapicker to other datapicker

Tags: wpf, binding, datepicker

I have 2 datapicker.
datapicker 1 binded at field1 database
datapicker 2 binded to field2 database.
i'd like to see the date of datapicker1 on datapicker2 if the field2 is null.
I saw that in VS on selecteddate property i can bind with the element name but do not understand the path to use.
thanks!

Comment: Please post some XAML markup and code that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In set part of the field1, check if field2 is null, if yes, then update the two fields to the same value.

```
private string _field1;
public string field1
{
   get { return _field1; }
   set
   {
       _field1= value;
       if(_field2 == null)
       {
            _field2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("field2");
       }
       RaisePropertyChangedEvent("field1");
   }
}
```

This solution is not using codeBehind. If you use it is quite simple: raise an event when the datepicker1 change and check it if field2 is null, if yes then set the same value of field1.